# Run the script only onclick on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Whenever my chrome extension icon is clicked, I want to run a script that would make certain changes to the current webpage.

I have tried using content_scripts in my manifest and it worked but the problem is , the script runs even if I did not clicked on the icon.

I have found that, I need to use background script.In my background.js file I have added

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert();
});
```

and it is not working.

Here is my manifest file.

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Reveal Password",
  "description": "Reveals password in password input field",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

Plus I want to execute the script that I made that manipulates the current web page too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to execute code in a tab like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'alert("Hello")'
  });
});
```

Instead of code, you could also use a file which contains the code :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

**NOTE :**  You need `activeTab` permissions to execute code in an active tab

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab"
]
```